# Ban command not functions properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im trying to make a ban command for my discord bot, but every time I send "s!ban [user]" the bot crashes, it leaves error message "Cannot read properties of undefined, reading (reading 'permissions')" my code:

```js
else if(message.content.startsWith("s!ban")){
    let user = message.author.username
    console.log(`${user} used s!ban`)
  let args = message.content.split(" ")
  member = message.mentions.members.first()
  const auth = message.author.id
  const permission = message.auth.permissions.has("BanMembers")
  if (!permission)
    return message.reply({ 
        contents: "You don't have permission to use this command"
    });

  if (!args[1]) return message.reply(`Please specify someone to ban!`);

  if (!member) return message.reply(`Sorry, I couldnt find that user!`);

  if (member.id === message.author.id)
    return message.reply({ content: `You cant ban yourself silly!` });

  if (message.member.roles.highest.position < member.roles.highest.position)
    return message.reply({
      content: `You cant ban a user who has a higher role than you silly!`
    });

  if (!member.bannable) return message.reply({ content: `Sorry, I cant ban that member`});

  return (
    (await member.ban()) +
    message
      .reply({
        content: `${member} has been banned successfully!`
      })
      .then((message) => {
        setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 5000);
      })
  );
    }
```

Comment: What is `message.auth`? There is no `auth` property on the `message` object. `message.auth.permissions` should be `message.member.permissions`.

Comment: i have auth defined as, message.author.id so it doesn't get mixed with member = message.mentions.members.first()

Comment: When you're using dot notation on an object you're accessing its properties, it has nothing to do with variables you declare elsewhere. If you declare a variable `member`, that variable has nothing to do with the property `member` of another object, ie `object.member`.

Comment: The closest thing to `message.auth` is `message.author`. Though this returns a User, which does not have permissions